# Symfony entity on Postgres view

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I need to map an entity to a Postgres view which doesn't have primary id, no id defined.

Views in Postgresql can't have primary keys. On the same time Doctrine entities need a primary key defined.

**Can I create a "virtual" property some like this?**

```
class MyEntityClass
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="uuid")
     */
     private $id;

     public function getId(): string
     {
          return generate_unique_id_just_for_my_join()
     }
 }
```

This entity need to be used only for select data. Never for insert/update.

Comment: Overriding getId is not going to help.  Doctrine itself transfers data directly between entity properties and table columns.  Check the Doctrine docs to see how to use compound keys for the id.

Comment: Ok i'll check thanks. This entity need to be used only for select data. Never for insert/update

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved using Doctrine somposite primary keys

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html